# Angular JS - Angular file doesn't respond to html (AngularJs with Spring Boot)

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-boot

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="main" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{firstName}}</p>
            <br>
            <p>{{lastName}}</p>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showLog()">MyButton</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('main',
function ($scope, $http, $state, $sce, urls) {

$scope.firstName = 'John';
$scope.lastName = 'Doe';

$scope.showLog = function () {
    console.log("angular works");
}

});
```

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and am just trying to connect Angular File with Html. so far I created the `showLog` function but pressing it does nothing at all. I feel like `ng-controller` does nothing and `{{firstName}}` & `{{lastName}}` are showing just like that (meaning the `'John' 'Doe'` don't get injected)

Also I have another question - If I'm loading the Angular file with `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>` , Why do I need to specify `ng-controller` ? shouldn't this already work?

[image: Console]

Comment: If you click on the link in the error message, it goes to a webpage that explains the error. [Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- main](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$stateProvider%20%3C-%20$state%20%3C-%20main). Providing text of the error message is more helpful than a picture. This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app module is not registered correctly. You need to instantiate like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('main',
function ($scope) {

$scope.firstName = 'John';
$scope.lastName = 'Doe';

$scope.showLog = function () {
    console.log("angular works");
}

});
```

In order to *start* the application , you need to use `ng-app` directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="main" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{firstName}}</p>
            <br>
            <p>{{lastName}}</p>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showLog()">MyButton</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-app` directive doesn't show in directives list when I type it, and also if I add the directive console then shows :

`angular.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: ng-app is required to be placed into the html of your app. Without that, the controller will not be instantiated. That is the console error?

Comment: I edited my question and added the image of the console

Comment: Ok check my edit. `angular.module('app', [])` this is the correct syntax to create a new module

Comment: It works, the only difference between our codes is that I have several unnecessary injections in my `function()` , removing everything except `$scope` & `$http` fixed the problem. Thank you very much good sir

Comment: It was the next thing I would suggest you to try to remove these injections

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.bootstrap` for connecting the app to specific html element.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', ['$scope', function exampleController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = 'John';
    $scope.lastName = 'Doe';

    $scope.showLog = function() {
      console.log("angular works");
    }
  }]);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" ng-controller="main" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>{{firstName}}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{{lastName}}</p>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showLog()">MyButton</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```